# C program error - outputting 0

Tags: c

I have been trying to get this to work for days now and I still cannot figure out the error. When I output the code, it prints, but it will not find the amicable pairs (divisor of first == second, and vice versa).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

int sumDivisors( int num );

int sumDivisors( int num )
{
  int counter, total;
  for( counter = 1; counter < num; counter++ )
    {
      if( num % counter == 0 )
        {
          total += counter;
        }
    }
  return ( total );
}

int main( void )
{
  int higher, lower, lowx, lowy, x, y, numOfPairs = 0;

  printf( "This program finds all amicable numbers within a range. \n" );
  printf( "Please enter a lower limit: \n" );
  scanf( "%d", &lower );
  printf( "Please enter a higher limit: \n" );
  scanf( "%d", &higher );


  for( lowx = lower; lowx <= higher; lowx++ )
    {
      for( lowy = lower; lowy <= higher; lowy++ )
        {
          if( sumDivisors( lowx ) == sumDivisors( lowy ) )
            {
              numOfPairs++;
              printf( "Pair #%d: (%d, %d)\n", numOfPairs, lowx, lowy );
            }
        }
    }

  printf( "There are %d amicable pairs from %d to %d\n", numOfPairs, lower, higher );
  system("pause");
  return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Consider writing the inner loop as `for( lowy = lowx + 1; lowy <= higher; lowy++ )` to avoid repetitions.

Comment: Good point, it makes it more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: On further thinking, you may have misinterpret the definition of amicable numbers, which are [two different numbers so related that the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers). You can find a list of the first pairs at [OEIS - A063990](http://oeis.org/A063990). Look at this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268160/4944425) for a more interesting optimization.

Comment: Yah, that was a logical error. I changed if( sumDivisors( lowx ) == sumDivisors( lowy ) ) to if( sumDivisors( lowx  ) == lowy && if( sumDivisors( lowy ) == lowx), and that worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assigning any value to total in your code:

```
int sumDivisors( int num )
{
  int counter, total;
  for( counter = 1; counter < num; counter++ )
    {
      if( num % counter == 0 )
        {
            total += counter;
        }
    }
  return ( total );
}
```

so it contains garbage not predictable value!

it should be like: `int counter, total = 0;`

Comment: Oh gosh... thank you... you saved me. I am used to null being zero

Comment: @Submersed24 What does it have to do with null being zero?

Comment: I used to think variables are defaulted at 0, so you don't need to set them to zero

Comment: @Submersed24, I'm glad that it helped! `:)`